# jQuery: calculate final total based on qty/price

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to calculate unit total and based on that final total using jQuery, I am able to update unit total every time qty or price is updated, but not able to update final total.

Here is the code:

```
<table id="tblUpdate" class="dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Unit Total</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <cfset TotalPrice = 0>
            <cfloop query="qItems">
                
                <cfset vLineID = qItems.LineID>
                <cfset vUnitTotal = qItems.Quantity * qItems.Price>
                <cfset TotalPrice = TotalPrice + vUnitTotal>
                
                <tr data-item-id="#qItems.ItemID#">
                        
                    <td>#qItems.ItemDescription#</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Quantity_#qItems.LineID#" id="Quantity#vLineID#" class="Quantity" onchange="ChangePrice(#vLineID#,'Quantity');" value="#NumberFormat(qItems.Quantity, '9.99')#" </td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="Price_#qItems.LineID#" id="UnitPrice#vLineID#" class="Price" onchange="ChangePrice(#vLineID#,'UnitPrice');" value="#NumberFormat(qItems.Price, '9.99')#" </td>
                    <td id="UnitTotal#vLineID#" class="UnitTotal">#NumberFormat(vUnitTotal,'9.99')#</td>
                </tr>
            </cfloop>
        </tbody>
        
        <tfoot>
            <td colspan="4"></td>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td id="TotalPrice_Total">#NumberFormat(TotalPrice,'9.99')#</td>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

And here if the Jquery: The unit total is updating every time when Qty and Price is updated, however, RefreshTotals() function is not updating. Its getting me values but not adding them and calculating final total.

```
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function()
   {

   function ChangePrice(LineID,FieldChanged) {
    
        var Quantity = document.getElementById("Quantity"+LineID);
        var UnitPrice = document.getElementById("UnitPrice"+LineID);
       var TotalPrice = 0;

       var vQuantity = Quantity.value;
       var vUnitPrice = UnitPrice.value;

       if (FieldChanged == "Quantity" || FieldChanged == "UnitPrice") {

          vCustomTotal = vQuantity * vUnitPrice;
    
         $('#UnitTotal' + LineID).text(vCustomTotal.toFixed(2));
        }

     refreshTotals();
  }

  function refreshTotals() {

   var vTotalPrice = 0;

      $('.UnitTotal').each(function(index) {
   
     var r = $("#tblUpdate.UnitTotal").text();
     vTotalPrice = vTotalPrice + r;
   });

     $('#TotalPrice_Total').text(vTotalPrice.toFixed(2));

}

}
</script>
```

Comment: You do not appear to close the `<input>` tag properly. Example: `<td><input type="text" name="Quantity_#qItems.LineID#" id="Quantity#vLineID#" class="Quantity" onchange="ChangePrice(#vLineID#,'Quantity');" value="#NumberFormat(qItems.Quantity, '9.99')#" </td>` No closing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {

  function formatCurrency(f) {
    return "$" + parseFloat(f).toFixed(2);
  }

  function refreshTotals() {
    var vTotalPrice = 0;
    var r;

    $(".UnitTotal").each(function(index, element) {
      r = parseFloat($(element).text().trim().substring(1));
      vTotalPrice += r;
    });

    $('#TotalPrice_Total').text(formatCurrency(vTotalPrice));
  }

  function changePrice(Row) {
    var Quantity = parseInt($(".Quantity", Row).val());
    var UnitPrice = parseFloat($(".Price", Row).val().substring(1));
    var TotalPrice = Quantity * UnitPrice;

    $(".UnitTotal", Row).html(formatCurrency(TotalPrice));

    refreshTotals();
  }

  $(".Quantity, .Price").change(function() {
    changePrice($(this).closest("tr"));
  });

  refreshTotals();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblUpdate" class="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Unit Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-item-id="01">
      <td>Item 01</td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" max="999" name="Quantity_01" id="Quantity01" class="Quantity" value="9" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Price_01" id="UnitPrice01" class="Price" value="$9.99" /> </td>
      <td id="UnitTotal01" class="UnitTotal">$89.91</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-item-id="02">
      <td>Item 02</td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" max="999" name="Quantity_02" id="Quantity02" class="Quantity" value="6" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Price_02" id="UnitPrice02" class="Price" value="$8.88" /> </td>
      <td id="UnitTotal01" class="UnitTotal">$53.28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-item-id="03">
      <td>Item 03</td>
      <td><input type="number" min="0" max="999" name="Quantity_03" id="Quantity03" class="Quantity" value="3" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Price_03" id="UnitPrice03" class="Price" value="$7.77" /> </td>
      <td id="UnitTotal03" class="UnitTotal">$23.31</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td>Total:</td>
    <td id="TotalPrice_Total">$0.00</td>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

When there are changes to Quantity or Price, the total Unit Price is updated along with the Total. We can pass in the `Row` and then collect all the details needed from that Row. The value of an input is String so it is best to cast it into the proper Integer or Float as needed. This will ensure that Math operations are correct.

Comment: I tweaked a bit but above code helped me! thanks.